# Keeping a java application open when a user selects "Cancel"?

Tags: java, events, dialog

I have a very basic question.

I have the following WIndowClosing() event in java. I want to keep the application open if the user clicks "Cancel". How do I do this?

The application keeps closing when "Cancel" is selected.

This is what I have:

```
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) 
    {
        SAVE_MODE event = m_model.saveChanges();

        if(event == SAVE_MODE.YES)
        {
            saveChanges();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if(event == Common.SAVE_MODE.NO)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            //Keep the application open -- how do I say that in code?
        }

    }
```

Note the following:

The application still closes when the ELSE clause is empty. I don't think that should be happening.

This should have taken me two minutes to solve. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you're calling [yourJFrame].setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: Thanks, ControlAltDel. I knew it would be something small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(if you want to credit me with the correct answer)

make sure you're calling [yourJFrame].setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

Comment: I want to credit you. My apologies for the late response. Thanks again, ControlAltDel.

Answer (score 1):

I think probably a different approach is all that's needed. Set your default close operation for the main frame (during your initial setup) to:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Then add your `windowClosing` code to exit on OK, and do nothing on Cancel.

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
        SAVE_MODE event = m_model.saveChanges();
        switch (event)
        {
            case YES:
                saveChanges();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            case NO:
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
  });
```